# $\iiint _E\;e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\;dV$ where E is enclosed by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ in the first octant.

Tags: integration

I just began practicing solving these integrals, but did the dumb mistake to make one of the questions I don't have the answer so I can check. Here it is.

Evualate $\iiint _E\;e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\;dV$, where E is enclosed by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ in the first octant.

I came with $\frac{1}{4}\pi^2 \left ( e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} - 1 \right)$.

If it's wrong don't explain how it's solved, just the answer so I can try again.

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

[EDIT]
Here is what I did.

---

$$\iiint _E\;e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\;dV = \iiint _E\;e^{\rho}\;dV\\
0\leq \rho\leq 9\\
0\leq\theta\leq \frac{1}{2}\pi\\
0\leq\phi\leq \frac{1}{2}\pi$$

---

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{0}^{9}e^\rho\;d\rho\; d\theta \;d\phi=\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\left [  e^\rho \right ]^9_0 \;d\theta \;d\phi=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}(e^9-1)\;d\theta\; d\phi=\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\left [(e^9-1)\;\theta \right ]_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\; d\phi=\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\frac{1}{2}\pi(e^9-1)\;d\phi = \frac{1}{4}\pi^2(e^9-1)$$

Comment: I get a different value.  The factor $\pi^2$ seems questionable.  Maybe you could show how you got there and we could give advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If spherical coordinates are given by
$$
\begin{gather}
x=\rho\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi}\\
y=\rho\sin{\theta}\sin{\varphi}\\
z=\rho\cos{\theta} 
\end{gather}
$$
then
$$dV=\rho^2 \sin{\theta}\,d{\rho}\,d{\theta}\,d{\varphi},$$
and
$$\iiint \limits_E\;e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\;dV=\int\limits_{0}^{3}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{e^{\rho}\rho^2 \sin{\theta}\,d{\rho}\,d{\theta}\,d{\varphi}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The range of $\rho$ should be $0$ to $3$ as it is $\rho^2$ that is less than $9$

You lost a factor of $\sin \theta$ in the angular integral.  As the integrand is spherically symmetric, the angular integrals should give $\frac \pi 2$, one eighth of the spherical surface area.

You also need a factor $\rho^2$ from the volume element.